# How to select distinct records with preference depending on a value

Tags: sql, distinct

i have this table :
[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQwUX.png)

notice that some ids have double records with IsTop = 1
if i have this kind of scenario im interested in selecting the one that has IsTop = 1 and if i dont im interested in keeping the one that IsTop = 0.

The goal is to have distinct Id's but take IsTop = 1 is it exists.

How do i do that?

Comment: Distinct applies to the entire row, so if there are differences the results you're returning won't be distinct and both will be returned.

Comment: I know, thats why im asking is there a way to get a distict id but depending on the value of a certain column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by isTop desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```